# I can't get a simple indexed array rendered properly

Tags: opengl, indexing, sample, opengl-4

I am porting this [sample](https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/OpenGLSamples/tree/master/samples/gl4-kepler/BindlessApp) ([site](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#gameworkslibrary/graphicssamples/opengl_samples/bindlessgraphicssample.htm)) to [jogl](https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/tree/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples) but I noticed something wasn't perfect in the image, some artefacts on the floor and shapes not exactly squared, as you can see (dont care about color, is varying), also the floor doesnt look good:

[image]

[image]

Therefore I tried to render only the floor first (if you wanna try, pretty easy, swith SQRT_BUILDING_COUNT from 100 -> 0) and there I have already the first problems, it is supposed to be a square based on two triangles, but I see only one of them.

[image]

[My vertex structure](https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/blob/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples/bindlessApp/util/Vertex.java):

```
public float[] position = new float[3];
public byte[] color = new byte[4];
public float[] attrib0 = new float[4];
public float[] attrib1 = new float[4];
public float[] attrib2 = new float[4];
public float[] attrib3 = new float[4];
public float[] attrib4 = new float[4];
public float[] attrib5 = new float[4];
public float[] attrib6 = new float[4];
```

attrib0-6 are unused at the moment

[My VS inputs](https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/blob/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples/bindlessApp/assets/shaders/simple_vertex.glsl#L41):

```
// Input attributes
layout(location=0) in vec4 iPos;
layout(location=1) in vec4 iColor;
layout(location=2) in PerMeshUniforms* bindlessPerMeshUniformsPtr;
layout(location=3) in vec4 iAttrib3;
layout(location=4) in vec4 iAttrib4;
layout(location=5) in vec4 iAttrib5;
layout(location=6) in vec4 iAttrib6;
layout(location=7) in vec4 iAttrib7;
```

I am declaring iPos as vec3, so I guess it will padded as vec4(iPos, 1) in the VS

[I transfer data to gpu](https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/blob/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples/bindlessApp/util/Mesh.java#L70):

```
    gl4.glNamedBufferData(vertexBuffer[0], Vertex.size() * vertices.size(),
            GLBuffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(verticesArray), GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl4.glNamedBufferData(indexBuffer[0], GLBuffers.SIZEOF_SHORT * indices.size(),
            GLBuffers.newDirectShortBuffer(indicesArray), GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then before I render [I call](https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/blob/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples/bindlessApp/util/Mesh.java#L148):

```
        gl4.glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(0, 0);
        gl4.glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(0, 1);
```

Then render, [original code is](https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/OpenGLSamples/blob/master/samples/gl4-kepler/BindlessApp/Mesh.cpp#L216):

```
    // Set up attribute 0 for the position (3 floats)
    glVertexArrayVertexAttribOffsetEXT(0, m_vertexBuffer, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), Vertex::PositionOffset);

    // Set up attribute 1 for the color (4 unsigned bytes)
    glVertexArrayVertexAttribOffsetEXT(0, m_vertexBuffer, 1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), Vertex::ColorOffset);
```

[I substituted it with](https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/blob/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples/bindlessApp/util/Mesh.java#L228):

```
        // Set up attribute 0 for the position (3 floats)
        gl4.glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(0, 0, vertexBuffer[0], Vertex.positionOffset,
                Vertex.size());
        gl4.glVertexArrayAttribFormat(0, 0, 3, GL4.GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.size());

        // Set up attribute 1 for the color (4 unsigned bytes)
        gl4.glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(0, 1, vertexBuffer[0], Vertex.colorOffset,
                Vertex.size());
        gl4.glVertexArrayAttribFormat(0, 1, 4, GL4.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, true, Vertex.size());
```

[And then I finish the render](https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/blob/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples/bindlessApp/util/Mesh.java#L302):

```
        // Reset state
        gl4.glDisableVertexArrayAttrib(0, 0);
        gl4.glDisableVertexArrayAttrib(0, 1);
```

I admit I never used dsa before, I always used GL3 with the normal vbo, vao and ibo, binding and unbinding..

Culling is off.

What's wrong then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was I didnt implement properly dsa

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vao, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vao, 1);

// Setup the formats
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);

// Setup the buffer sources
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, buffers[0], 0, 0); // Note the 2nd argument here is a 'binding index', not the attribute index
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 1, buffers[1], 0, 0);

// Link them up
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 0, 0); // Associate attrib 0 (first 0) with binding 0 (second 0).
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 1, 1);
```

plus `glVertexArrayElementBuffer` if you have indexed rendering